# Set an attribute of a object with a string attribute name in PHP

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I want to be able to set an attribute of an object but the attribute name would be generated. How can I accomplish this in PHP, without using `eval()`

e.g.:

```
$obj->name = "Prakash Raman"; // Works
$obj->$attr_name = <some value>; // Would want something like this to work
```

I would like to be able to change `$attr_name`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$obj->{$attr_name} = "New value";
```

This will accomplish exactly that.

A word of caution though, I would reccomend using it in conjunction with [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) to verify the existence of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, your code as posted will work. (++ for property_exists, though.)

http://codepad.org/qW0Tj4MR

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question has a valid answer, but just to add onto the many ways you can do this:

```
<?php
$myClass = new ReflectionClass($someClass);
if($myClass->hasProperty($someProperty)){
   $myClass->getProperty($someProperty)->setValue($someClass,__NEW__VALUE__);
}
?>
```